# Get friend profile detail in taggable_friends facebook API iphone-sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

In my old application I am downloading the Facebook friends in my application but that API is removed so now I am using `"taggable_friends"` API in my application but it only returns the friends name and one other ID. So please suggest how can I also get the other fields of friends like (DOB, userID etc) please suggest.
Thanks
Mitesh

Comment: Taggable_friends is for tagging people. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't let you access profile friend anymore. They just let you get friend use your ap:

> My app needs the list of someone's friends that don't use the app. Can
>   I have access to this info?
>
> The list of someone's friends who don't use your app is no longer
>   available in v2.0. However, you can still enable people to tag friends
>   using the Taggable Friends API. Also, If your app is categorized as a
>   game and you have a presence on Facebook Canvas, you can use the
>   Invitable Friends API to render a custom invites dialog within your
>   game. However, you'll still need to pass the tokens returned by the
>   Invitable Friends API to the Requests Dialog to actually send the
>   invites.

You just can get more detail if friend of this user also use your app too. Reference to this link:  [Get friend use app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends)